# Import into Solr not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to import cvs file data into remote Solr.

My command is:

```
curl "http://mydomain.io/solr/#/qacheck/update?commit=true" --data-binary "d:\maincat.csv" -H "Content-type:application/csv"
```

I am getting output like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/index.html. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And after I tried like this:

```
curl "http://proxy.sip.solr.qacheck1.test9.mcc.gb-lon1.metroscales.io/solr/qacheck/update?commit=true" --data-binary "d:\maincat.csv" -H "Content-type:application/csv"
```

Now I am getting this response. I verified, no data imported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">3</int></
lst>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#` in URLs indicates a local anchor. This value is never exposed to the server, and is only used internally in the browser to link to a specific part of a page - or in many modern web applications, to keep some local state about the current javascript context. In the first URL above, you've included the browser part of the URL and not used the actual URL to the update handler.

In your second attempt you're not including the file, just the verbatim text `d:\maincat.csv`. If you want curl to read a file and submit its content (instead of submitting the verbatim path), [you have to prefix the value with `@`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary). So `--data-binary "@d:\maincat.csv"` should do what you want.